# Ui-Grid CellTemplate does not behave as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I'm working on dashboard for monitoring jobs and the status is updated 
butt the `cellTemplate` in Ui-Grid does not behave as expected 
here what  I have tried

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [{
        field: 'Id'
      }, {
        field: 'Job'
      }, {
        field: 'status',
        cellTemplate:'<div>{{grid.appScope.applyStatus(row.entity.status)}}</div>'
        //note  this work well 

       // cellTemplate:'<div><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>'

      }]
    };
```

and this function should update the status with a fontawesome Icon

```
  $scope.applyStatus= function(status) {
      switch(status)
            {

                case "Pending" :
                   return  '<i class="label-info fa-pause" />'; 

                case "Running" : return '<i class="label-primary fa-play-circle-o" />'
                case "Error" :
                    return '<i class="label-danger  fa-bug" />';                                                                                   
                default:
                    return '<i class="label-default fa-box fa fa-question"/>';

            }   

    return 

};
```

But instead of rendering what I expected Angulars treat this as if a text

here a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/7UapXgNzZWPXVZbLjYFy?p=preview

any help with a good underhood explanation will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it using ng-class.  http://plnkr.co/edit/lRuP4agztDo7kxEO5VE6?p=preview

CellTemplate:

```
<div><text><i ng-class="grid.appScope.applyStatus(row.entity.status)"/></text></div>
```

Comment: Ok great that's work but why the cell template is behaving like this??

Comment: {{}} is used for evaluating expressions and on scope variables.

Comment: I don't know any. I feel that the solution given by me is better than using ng-bind-html. Anyway, I don't know the pros and cons.